# for loop in Antlr4

Tags: antlr, antlr4

By and large, I'm trying to make something like this: [Parsing a loop with ANTLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674801/parsing-a-loop-with-antlr). But what is `input.Mark()` and `input.Rewind()`? It isn't defined for me, is it the same as `InputStream.Mark()` and `InputStream.Release`? Please forgive me for my illiteracy. Let's say I tried to do something like this:

```
forloop returns [object result]
    @init {int mark = InputStream.Mark();}
    :   FOR v=VAR FROM a=equation TO b=equation DO NL
        {
            string v = $v.text;
            if (!memory.Keys.Contains(v))
                memory.Add(v, (int)$a.result);
        }
        body=lines ENDLOOP 
        {
            if (memory[v] < $b.result) {
                $result = $body.result;
                memory[v] += 1;
                InputStream.Release(mark);
            }
        }
    ;
```

Comment: I'd strongly recommend that you don't implement loops by parsing the loop body repeatedly. If you don't want to generate bytecode, at least use a visitor.

Comment: The question you linked to is from 10 years ago and was for ANTLR v3. I recommend you do not embed code inside your grammar, but do the evaluation inside a visitor after parsing.

Comment: Сould you show a simple example of solution this task using a visitor then? I've seen some docs/videos but most of them are too old or explained not well. Preferably step by step, if it isn't hard for you.

Comment: I have a small toy language here that supports loops and has a visitor that evaluates it all: https://github.com/bkiers/tiny-language-antlr4

Comment: Use @BartKiers example.  It's a good one.